# Ruby on Rails - button_to using routes to call function from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, button-to

Hello right now I've a problem about button_to

I want to setup a button that call a method in controller, this is how I setup the button :

(this located in issues/_edit.html.erb)

```
<%= button_to "Cancel Return", :action => "cancel_return", :controller => "issues" %>
```

and I want this will call this function in issues_controller.rb

```
  def cancel_return
    @issue.cancel_return(params)
  end
```

I also added it in the routes.rb

```
map.issue_cancel_return 'issues/cancel_return', :controller => 'issues',
                       :action => 'cancel_return'
```

but it can't work, I already tried to declare cancel_return as helper_method, but it also didn't work. is there any other solution? or I'm doing it wrong? I'm using ruby version 1.9.3p125 and rails version 2.3.15, I used old version because I tried to modify redmine, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is issues#cancel_return a valid route? i haven't seen redmine's routes.rb but did you also the new action in there aside from adding it in the controller?

Comment: @roninblade actually I'm not actually sure how to put it in the routes.rb, I added it like this    map.issue_cancel_return 'issues/cancel_return', :controller => 'issues',
                       :action => 'cancel_return', you can also see it in the edited question

Comment: what happens when you call the action directly on your browser? ie. http://127.0.0.1:3000/issues/cancel_return/?plus_your_extra_params

Comment: @roninblade error 403 not auothorized even I'm login to the site as admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be putting them in a curly braces like this

```
<%= button_to "Cancel Return", { :controller => "issues", :action => "cancel_return"} %>
```

what happening is that `map` is not defining the method for the call like GET/POST/DELETE
so what you can do is use this instead of you `map` line in your `routes.rb` file

```
get "issues/cancel_return" => "issues#cancel_return"
```

this should solve your problem.

Comment: still nothing happens :(, how can I know the function is called beside the database change? is there any method like php print_r("TEXT");exit; in RoR?just to make sure my button works

Comment: look at you server log, that what request is being happening and what is called and what not.

Comment: I guess it's not called the last 3 action showed in the log after I clicked the button is Processing IssuesController#show (for 172.16.20.1 at 2013-08-28 11:42:16) [GET]
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"issues", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"833"}
Rendering template within layouts/base
Rendering issues/show
Completed in 408ms (View: 65, DB: 316) | 200 OK 

do you know why it's not called?

Comment: @nayoso can you please write the path that you have given in the routes.rb, show what poppes out with both `show` and `cancel_return` methods.

Comment: i meant do `rake paths` and tell me what method each action is showing  you know like 'get/put/delete' types

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36372/discussion-between-dirtydexter-and-nayoso)